# Hide excel file in mac system?

Tags: excel, applescript

How to hide the excel file on mac system using apple script . I am using some following steps.

```
   tell application "Microsoft Excel"
       make new workbook 
       set visible to false
   end tell
```

This script run is successfully and hide the excel application. But see the instance of excel file in docklet . I want to hide the excel instance in docklet. 
If excel instance is hide in docklet (some setting are follow Go to folder

1. Applications
2. Microsoft Office 2011
3. Left click On Microsoft Excel
4. Show package Contents
5. contents
6. Info.plist
7. click Add new child
8. Add new child is **Application is Agent(UIElement)** with check box true
   If follow some steps then excel instance is not show in docklet but excel file is not hide.

Answer (score 0):

This will toggle the visibility of a file...

```
set f to choose file with invisibles
tell application "System Events"
    set visible of f to not (visible of f)
end tell
```

***EDIT***: You can hide Excel with this...

```
tell application "System Events"
    set visible of process "Microsoft Excel" to false
end tell
```

Comment: Hide the excel file which created by the make new workbook command not choose file dialog.

Comment: In your script data is not enter in excel file after open the excel file in choose file dialog.

Comment: I added an EDIT section to my post. Maybe that's what you're looking for?